# HTTP Video Streaming in Rails 3+

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, http, video

I need some help with the below:

Ok the scenario is this: I am contacting a server and from the server I am getting this URI:

```
http://<camera_ip_address>/<type_ID>/<part_ID>
```

The documentation of this webservice says:

```
"The part_ID will vary from part_start and part_end."
```

I got all the data needed. Now what I dont get is how this is related to HTTP video streaming?

If I have part_start = 1 and part_end = 10, that means that I will "download" 10 frames?
How? with curl? wget? Rails?

Should a loop be implemented like (example):

```
for i=1; i<10 i++
   download "http://127.0.0.1/34/i"
end
```

What will "http://127.0.0.1/34/10" for example be? a png/jpeg frame file?
Any help will be very useful. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, rails isn't really relevant here.

It looks like you just need to utilize some flash player here, one of the most popular ones is [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12538/supported-player-embed-methods)

See the SWFOBJECT section. basically, you have to do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var flashvars = { file:'http://<camera_ip_address>/<type_ID>/',autostart:'true' };
  var params = { allowfullscreen:'true', allowscriptaccess:'always' };
  var attributes = { id:'player1', name:'player1' };

  swfobject.embedSWF('player.swf','container1','480','270','9.0.115','false',
    flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am restricted to html 5