# How to stream video through http in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, video-streaming

How do I add video streaming functionality in my Rails application given the fact that another server will send me the video http packets, and I just need to stream them to the client? any guidance ? tutorials help?

Answer (score 1):

well, I believe html5  tag should do the trick. since you do not need to convert anything and there's a server that can serve your video streaming you could simply use something like:

```
<video width="100" height="50" controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer">
    <source src="http://streaming-server.com/videos/video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="http://streaming-server.com/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

there're both `ogg` and `mp4` versions to support both chrome/safari and firefox.

Comment: hey thanks for the response but my issue is actually this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029666/http-video-streaming-in-rails-3. It is a very low-level HTTP network matter. Sadly it is not as simple as a simple url insertion